# How to count number of different IPs that have accessed certain URL from Apache access log?

Tags: apache, grep

I'm doing something like
zgrep "somepattern" access_log.X.gz 
But I find that a lot of the entries are from the same IP and I'd like to count them as one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use something like

```
zgrep "somepattern" access_log.X.gz | awk '{print $3}' | sort -u | wc -l
```

`awk` is to print out the field that contains the client IP address (I'm assuming it's the third field here, but adjust the number to match your log format), then `sort -u` sorts the IP addresses and removes duplicates, then `wc -l` counts the number of lines.